# File is not being uploaded using RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, remotewebdriver

I am trying to upload a file in a demo site using remoteWebDriver but it is not getting uploaded. I have successfully implemented with the WebDriver driver but was trying using RemoteWebDriver.
The exception I am getting is :"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Setting the file detector only works on remote webdriver instances obtained via RemoteWebDriver". Can someone please help?

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class UsingRemoteWebDriver {
    WebDriver driver;
    String url = "https://practice-cybertekschool.herokuapp.com/upload";
    By browseButton = By.id("file-upload");
    By uploadButton = By.id("file-submit");

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    public void uploadFile() throws InterruptedException {
        File uploadFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\test.au3");
        ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        WebElement browseElement = driver.findElement(browseButton);
        browseElement.sendKeys(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

`

Exception is: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Setting the file detector only works on remote webdriver instances obtained via RemoteWebDriver
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is caused by the fact, that your driver is actually an **EdgeDriver**

To set the file detector you should use an instance of the **RemoteWebDriver** as the error suggests.

So you have to change this:

> driver = new EdgeDriver();

to this:

> driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("..."), new ChromeOptions());

See [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/) and [this example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium/drivers/RemoteWebDriverTest.java#L35-L55)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this Selenium Official document for more information.

> https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/

It will give you idea what is missing. Here, you need to find out the input box that have the tag with type=file. without **type=file** you can not upload anything. you required to use Robot class if you want to upload any thing.

You can refer to this git page and explore coding.

> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium/drivers/RemoteWebDriverTest.java#L48-L51